# What is the difference between using '*' and '.*' in the first line of a select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm hoping if someone could explain the difference between the two following statements:

```
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

and

```
SELECT employee.* FROM employee;
```

If someone could provide their reasoning for choosing employee.* instead of *, or when it would be appropriate to choose one over the other, it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Joe.

Comment: No difference  .. the firts use impict table name the second esplicit tablename

Comment: I am a strong advocate of qualifying all column references, so I consider the second method to be better (although I would use a table alias called `e`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT * ...`

selects all columns from the result set generated in the `FROM` clause.

---

`SELECT employees.* ...`

selects all columns in the result set generated in the `FROM` clause that originated from the `employees` table (note that `employees` may also be an alias rather than a table name).

---

When the `FROM` clause only contains a single table, those two describe the same set of columns.<sup>1</sup>

As to why someone has chosen to write it this way when only a single table is present, I couldn't say. If they were an absolutist who insisted on prefixing all columns in the `select` clause with their originating table, I'm surprised that they're comfortable using `*` in there at all rather than explicit column names.

---

<sup>1</sup>But note that it's the `FROM` clause (including any `JOIN`s etc) and the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses that affect *which rows* are displayed. The `SELECT` clause effectively chooses columns.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Damien. Definitely helps!

Answer (score 2):

In your example there is no difference. The reason the syntax allows for this is to allow you to display all the columns from only one object in your `FROM` clause. It would make more sense with an example.

---

The following query will display all columns from both tables `employee` and `manager`

```
SELECT * FROM employee inner join manager on employee.managerid = manager.managerid
```

---

The following query is functionally equivalent to the one above it the difference being is that we explicitly specify the order of the tables in the displayed column set.

```
SELECT employee.*, manager.* FROM employee inner join manager on employee.managerid = manager.managerid
```

---

The following query will only display columns from table `employee` and *not* `manager`

```
SELECT employee.* FROM employee inner join manager on employee.managerid = manager.managerid
```